# SIFT algorithm and KD tree

Tags: algorithm, sift, kdtree

I'm actually trying to implement image matching using SIFT algorithm.
But I'm actually stuck, and I wonder if you can help me.

I have the first step ( the descriptors, with x and y, and all the 128 features vectors ) and I'm now trying to do the KD-tree in order to search the nearest neighbor of each descriptors. I understood the concept of kd-tree, but I don't understand on what I have to separate the descriptors. I have to make the KD-tree based on their (x,y)? If yes, how can it helps me, since I have to find the nearest neighbor using the descriptor? Maybe I have not understand what I had to understand?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards!

Comment: I do not know the SIFT algorithm. But looking on wikipedia it says that the high dimensionality is a problem, so I think you have to construct a single feature vector from all points of interested. In that case, kd-trees are rather bad, I would go with a Covertree, maybe an R-Tree variant or with my very own Ph-tree (www.phtree.org). However, while the latter is good for kNN queries, it is limited to 60 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I'll take a look at all of this!  
I'm actually looking at OpenCV implementation, but it seems quit hard. 
Your ph-tree won't work for 128 dimensions, right?
Thanks a lot!